# How to get records related to highest sessioncount in a given day

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a App Insights table like below  expected output is : need to select the processDate and its related fields which has highest aggregate value of sessionCount in that day (yellow highlighted rows are the expected result)

```
let da = datatable(id:int, processDate:datetime, message:string,col:string, sessionCount:int)
    [
        1,"2021-03-03 12:00:00", "a","aa",2,
        1,"2021-03-03 12:00:00", "a","aa2",8,
        1,"2021-03-03 09:00:00", "g","gg",20,
        1,"2021-03-03 09:00:00", "g","g1",3,
        1,"2021-03-03 15:00:00", "b","bb",9,
        1,"2021-03-03 15:00:00", "b","bb1",1,
        2,"2021-03-07 21:00:00", "f","ff",6,
        2,"2021-03-07 21:00:00", "f","ff",2,
        2,"2021-03-07 21:00:00", "abc","faf",21,
        2,"2021-03-07 22:00:00", "abc","fav",25,
        2,"2021-03-07 22:00:00", "z","zz",9
    ];
    
    da 
    | summarize maxsessionCountperRun = sum(sessionCount) by  processDate  
;
```

expected out is below
[image: expected output is]

Comment: what is the question? Can you provide the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: What would be the expected result in case the max value of sessionCount per processDate  appears more than once?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz, Thank you for checking . there is no possibility of max sessionCount value and process date appearing more than once. If it happens selecting one of them is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let da = datatable(id:int, processDate:datetime, message:string,col:string, sessionCount:int)
    [
        1,"2021-03-03 12:00:00", "a","aa",2,
        1,"2021-03-03 12:00:00", "a","aa2",8,
        1,"2021-03-03 09:00:00", "g","gg",20,
        1,"2021-03-03 09:00:00", "g","g1",3,
        1,"2021-03-03 15:00:00", "b","bb",9,
        1,"2021-03-03 15:00:00", "b","bb1",1,
        2,"2021-03-07 21:00:00", "f","ff",6,
        2,"2021-03-07 21:00:00", "f","ff",2,
        2,"2021-03-07 21:00:00", "abc","faf",21,
        2,"2021-03-07 22:00:00", "abc","fav",25,
        2,"2021-03-07 22:00:00", "z","zz",9
    ];
da
| summarize sum(sessionCount) by processDate  
| summarize arg_max(sum_sessionCount, processDate) by processDate_day = bin(processDate,1d) 
| project-away processDate_day
```

| sum_sessionCount | processDate |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 2021-03-03T09:00:00Z |
| 34 | 2021-03-07T22:00:00Z |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/demo12.westus/databases/GitHub?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA5WS3WrDMAyF7wN5B%20GrBFywXbotGb3q3mKMIMdu8MjPSNxtDXv4KSsj7kpHKptjI31H6EK19WAQtiSejq5t4kzuWs/hre9KOwxP6G1OVetdYzk0lMLK5oPvXVvxsqt/vzBQyXXtrju0fmqRxhFQPJ%20eKSRnSii5Emu6IFUuBF3GgSHjDEkUX04rxh%20u4iKb8YrwikSJ5bhkfH19ls1Ma6I1SXYDTc1lgKsAvwclZ3xP%20J7k7iZaLaJRlxOPk%20GfadSl450cm0WOkfiRJDvBL49xZDCOvmA4NA32brTTLwk3JwV9DHcP4JzHvioa/EwoU4S%20s4X926QweKQl165NgiyXJv3pTrlXW/oVfuCF7RvOsBY4IgMAAA==)

Comment: Thanks David, It seems to be working but did not understand  how the " sum(sessionCount) " in the 1st summarize is being used in the second summarize argmax statement. as i dont see any reference to the sum(sessionscount) value in the argmax.

Comment: KQL magic :-) It is being automatically aliased as `sum_sessionCount`